# Disable hand symbol when hovering over a link

Tags: html, css

I want to disable a decoration in any hyper link means when we hover a link then we get a hand symbol instead of mouse cursor. I want to disable it .Whenever i hover mouse on a link it  should just show mouse cursor but not hand symbol.

Comment: a {
    cursor: text;
} or use

Comment: Why? That's an important usability feature.

Comment: Cursor shapes should meet user's expectations – in good UI design they indicate the [*affordance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance) of the control. If the control is not a hyperlink or something that you would consider a form of button which you would press your finger or hand on if you could (and nowadays [you *can*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchscreen)), do not use an `a` element in the first place.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the CSS [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) property to get this.

- Use `default` to get a pointer like when not hovering over any text
- Use `text` to get a text-selection cursor like when hovering over non-link text

```
a {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Nc5CS/

Answer (score 4):

```
a
{
    cursor:default;
}
```

Arrow is default symbol for hover on link.So use cursor:default if cursor is other than arrow or hand.

Answer (score 2):

Use this css:

```
a {
    cursor: default;
}
```